# PyQt6: Removing ALL padding around widget

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget, pyqt6, qlayout

I'm trying push two QLineEdit-widgets all the way up to each other, but no matter how and when i call `setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)` , it just does not seem to remove all margins. I've tried googling, but all comments just say "use `layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)`", and that's it. Can somebody explain to me why this doesn't work in my example and how to fix it?

Code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit
enter image description hereimport sys

class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.qlineedit1 = QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit1.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.qlineedit2 = QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit2.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.general_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.general_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.general_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit1)
        self.general_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit2)

        self.setLayout(self.general_layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TimeWidget1()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Window that appears:

[image: There is clearly a gap here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to call `layout.setSpacing(0)`

Code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit
enter image description hereimport sys

class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.qlineedit1 = QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit1.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.qlineedit2 = QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit2.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.general_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.general_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.general_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit1)
        self.general_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit2)

        self.setLayout(self.general_layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TimeWidget1()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Result:

[image: No padding to speak of]